# What will PDOStatement::fetch() or fetchAll() method return when no records found? (PHP + MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
$stmt = $dbh->query($query);
$array = $stmt->fetch();
$stmt->closeCursor();
```

What would fetch() or fetchAll() method return when no records were found?

- An empty array?
- A non-empty array with field names as the keys and
  NULLs as the values?
- A NULL value?
- A FALSE value?
- Or just to trigger an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is a FALSE, after I tested it myself.